# Use tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables a monster and a tag table, and a monster_tag table in between. I want to be able to show all the monsters that share the same tag by reading the monster_tag table.Would it be better if I wrote the feature from scratch, or use the act-as-taggable gem. If I pick the act-as-taggable gem, how would I configure it to use the monster_tag table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For functionality you described setting up has_many through relationships should be enough.

You can get all monsters that share the same tag with something like `Tag.find(name: 'tag').monsters`

Comment: Thanks, I have it set up. I having another issue, when  search I am getting results of the same monster. How do I hide duplicate results?

Comment: @monster_tag_search = "Set Name MonsterTag".tr(" ","").constantize.all

Comment: <% @monster_tag_search.each do |tag| %>
<%= tag.monster_id %>
<% end %>

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do with this `@monster_tag_search = "Set Name MonsterTag".tr(" ","").constantize.all`